# Obvious duplicate still alive, close vote gone — why oh why?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close, reopen-closed

Back in '11, I must have voted to close this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7117142/visual-basic-evaluation-of-a-string#comment8529584_7117142

as a duplicate of this one: [Doing math in vb.net like Eval in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452282/doing-math-in-vb-net-like-eval-in-javascript)

Which it is. Totally.

Yet it's alive and well today, and has zero close votes.

I say "must have", because I don't remember casting that particular vote, but now when I try to cast a close vote, I can't, because it says I have already done so.

- Does this mean it's been re-opened by someone?
- If so, **why** would someone do that?

This is not the first time I bump into this situation. **An even more egregious example:**

- [conditionally concatenate text from multiple records in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043397/conditionally-concatenate-text-from-multiple-records-in-vba)
- [conditionally concatenate text from multiple records in vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7043629/conditionally-concatenate-text-from-multiple-records-in-vba)

A duplicate question by the same user, with identical titles (I didn't even know this was technically possible). I voted to close as such, but now it's, I guess, reopened. Again, why?

Comment: Apparently my close vote [died of old age](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271745/119775). Maybe someone will close those dupes on my behalf?

Comment: If you have questions or tags that need some attention from close voters feel free to drop a message in [SO Close Voters room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers)

Comment: [I lol'd](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1452295/1228)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As can be seen from the revision history, the question wasn't ever closed.

You cast a close vote, the close vote aged away over time, which is why there are no current close votes on the question, and why you can't cast a new vote to close.